# MVC i want to insert client data ip address,and date on database now but action not done

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

```
 MBG_ITEntities db = new MBG_ITEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HitCounter obj)
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            obj.IPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
            obj.CreateDate = time;
            db.HitCounter.Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(obj);
        }
```

i want action done on load page.
i want the action done from controller only

Comment: this is my js code
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")/',
            type: "POST",
        });
    });
   
</script>

Comment: Hi, can you share the complete javascript/jquery code snippet for how you pass the `HitCounter` object to API via ajax? Thanks.

Comment: I only use the mentioned codes, please, if there is anything missing in the code, let me know, thank you   <script> $(document).ready(function () { $.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")/', type: "POST", }); }); </script>

Comment: Recreate the [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NXC9tu). Checked F12 + Network tab, the `Home/Index` POST is fired. Did you try to put the breakpoint in your POST method to see the method is fired? Meanwhile, why don't you move the insert HitCounter logic to `Index()` GET method? As the Index() GET is to load the page. Which you don't need to additionally call the POST method in ajax to insert HitCounter.